# Handling positions in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have fiddled with the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for quite some time now. It's really a great tool to populate a custom list/recycler view very fast with all of its features. However, one thing that I would like to ask is how to handle positions of items inside the adapter itself.

So for example, I want to mimic this small feature that WhatsApp has in their chats.

[image]

So, in a group chat setting, if a person sends more than one consecutive message in a row, the display name of that particular person will be invisible.

The logic behind it according to my understanding: if the person who sends the message is the same for (position - 1), then I will just make the EditText invisible for (position). This is, of course, to prevent a very long stream of text with minimum amounts of repetitive information.

Let's say the JSON tree from Firebase database is as follows.

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "pushed_id_1" : {
      "message_sender" : "AppleJuice",
      "message_text" : "Are you free?"
    },
    "pushed_id_2" : {
      "message_sender" : "AppleJuice",
      "message_text" : "On Saturday I mean..."
    }
  }
}
```

The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter would look like this.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(Message.class, R.layout.message_item, MessageViewHolder.class, myRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MyBookingsViewHolder viewHolder, Booking model, int position) {
                viewHolder.messageSender.setText(model.getMessage_sender());
                viewHolder.messageText.setText(model.getMessage_text());

                //put some code here to implement the feature that we need
            }
        };
        messages_recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The furthest I have gone is to use getItemCount() method in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but I am still unable to achieve the feature that mimics that of Whatsapp's that I was talking about previously.

Is there a method that can achieve this? Or am I missing something very important in this example?

Comment: You need to keep reference of sender's name OR **ID** every time so that when next message arrives you can **compare** and make messageSender visiblity **GONE** because **INVISIBLE** takes the space  on screen.

Comment: So what is the problem, how to know the position of current `ViewHolder` you mean?

Comment: @Wizard yes, but more of that, getting both the position of a specific item in a ViewHolder AND referencing the EditText in that specific position. Is it possible to achieve this with any methods in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: To get the position, you can use `holder.getAdapterPosition()`. I don't understand the rest.

Comment: @Sara Tirmizi ah yes, I have already tried that as well (in case the name is exactly the same) I can use the FirebaseAuth uid to get that. But the problem I'm facing is how to compare it as I am unable to find a way to reference an EditText in a specific position.

Comment: @Wizard I will try that and update you here

Comment: @applejuice why do you need to take edittext reference? 
For Example:
Let suppose I received message and stored name in constant String that should be static constant in come class so that It can be accessed everywhere therefore in **populateViewHolder**. 
`if (TextUtils.isEqual(storedSender,model.getMessage_sender())){  viewHolder.messageSender.setVisiblity(View.GONE) }` else{  // do your normal flow viewHolder.messageSender.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE); storedSender = model.getMessage_sender();  }

Comment: @Sara Tirmizi thank you for the answer, according to your code does that mean that there could be only one sender name that you store under the variable storedSender? Because if for example the chat group has 30 people, then I would have to store the sender name in 29 different variables? Is there a generalised way of referring to the person id of the previous message instead? (which is why I am asking about how to get a specific edittext/uid element of an item in the RecyclerView position)

Comment: @applejuice no , since it is a constant available in say suppose **AppConstants** class then in your firebase message receiver update this constant storedSender only , in this way automatically the last message's sender's name will be update , this is exactly what you were trying to achieve by adapter position!

Comment: @Sara Tirmizi OH! I think i get where you're getting at now. Assuming if the populate viewholder method populates from pos[0] to pos[n] chronologically, we keep updating the storedSender variable when it isn't the same as previous position (which is in the code you put in the "else" section of your previous answer). I'll try this out! It seems that I've been too stuck with the idea of getting the postion reference that I didn't think of this kind of solution! Thank you for the answer and I will keep you posted.

Comment: sure , my pleasure @applejuice if it works do update so that I can refactor my comment as answer so that you may mark checked for the benefit of others.! #HappyCoding :)

Comment: yes, you can post it as an answer! Thank you very much! I've tried it and it works!

Comment: That's great #HappyCoding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As discussed in comments:

Let's suppose I received message and stored sender's name in constant String that should be static constant in some class i.e. AppConstants so that It can be accessed everywhere therefore after that:

> in **populateViewHolder** or in your message receiver do something like this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEqual(storedSender,model.getMessage_sender())){ 
        viewHolder.messageSender.setVisiblity(View.GONE) 
       } 
    else{ 
        // do your normal flow 
        viewHolder.messageSender.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE); 
    storedSender = model.getMessage_sender(); 
    }
```

In this way automatically the last message's sender's name will be updated , this is exactly what you were trying to achieve by adapter position!

Answer (score 2):

```
String lastSender=null; //or some random string

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder> adapter = 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>
(Message.class, R.layout.message_item, MessageViewHolder.class, myRef) {

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(MyBookingsViewHolder viewHolder, Booking model, int position) {
if (model.getMessage_sender().equals(lastSender){   //check if the current sender is same as the last sender
    viewHolder.messageText.setText(model.getMessage_text());    //setting only message text
    viewHolder.messageSender.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //if required
}else{
    lastSender=model.getMessage_sender();//updating the lastSender value
    viewHolder.messageSender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   //if required
    viewHolder.messageSender.setText(model.getMessage_sender());
    viewHolder.messageText.setText(model.getMessage_text());
}
     //put some code here to implement the feature that we need
}

};

messages_recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was also suggested by @Sara Tirmizi earlier and it works! (I will wait for Sara's answer and accept that instead since she answered earlier. Sorry about that but thank you very much for taking your time to post this answer)

Comment: Okay sure. Great.